# DynamoDB "Invalid UpdateExpression" when running in javascript but not in the command line

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to figure out this error in dynamodb. I want to increment a number in an attribute using the add operator. I ran the following code

```
•––– aws dynamodb update-item --table-name my-table \
    --key '{"id": {"S": "12356"}}' \
    --update-expression "ADD myattribute :val" \
    --expression-attribute-values '{":val": {"N": "1"}}' \
```

Which works fine, I can see the item being updated. So I tried implementing the equivalent method in typescript

```
  public async increment(
    id: string
  ): Promise<void> {
    await this.db.update({
      TableName: this.tableName,
      Key: {
        "id": { S: id },
      },
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":val": { N: "1" }
      },
      UpdateExpression: "ADD myattribute :val"
    }).promise()
  }
```

Now if one works, I'd expect the other to work too. However, I run into the issue

```
ValidationException: Invalid UpdateExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator: ADD, operand type: MAP, typeSet: ALLOWED_FOR_ADD_OPERAND
```

Why does it work in the CLI but not using the aws client in typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my assumption, but I believe you are using the `DocumentClient` in javascript, which does not use DynamoDB-JSON but rather native JSON:

```
  public async increment(
    id: string
  ): Promise<void> {
    await this.db.update({
      TableName: this.tableName,
      Key: {
        "id": id,
      },
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":val": 1
      },
      UpdateExpression: "ADD myattribute :val"
    }).promise()
  }
```